# Cocoa document-based application with multiple document types

Tags: cocoa, macos, document-based

I want to build a document-based app in Cocoa but so that it can create and handle different types of documents. Think Word, Excel, Powerpoint all in one application, only much simpler. But every window will be different based on the type of document.

For storage I will use CoreData. I think of adding a field that specifies the type of document since they should all have the same file ending.

So without creating several independent apps what would be the best way to go about it? How do I create this in Interface Builder? How do I code this up?

I don't need detailed source code or anything, just the general idea of how to do this, I will figure the rest out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 15):

This is something the Cocoa Document system is explicitly designed to do. Apple [provides documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Documents.html), but here are the highlights.

- Each kind of document is a subclass of `NSDocument`. If you're using Core Data, base your class on `NSPersistentDocument` instead. (Apple has a [basic tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/NSPersistentDocumentTutorial/00_Introduction/introduction.html) on how to use Core Data in a document-based application)
- You tell Cocoa about the kinds of documents your application can open, and which document class to use, with the [Info.plist](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Documents/Tasks/ImplementingDocApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000029).
- Each `NSDocument` subclass has one or more `NSWindowController` objects associated with it, each of which represents a single window. If you'll only have a single window, you don't have to subclass `NSWindowController`. You can put your UI logic in your document subclass. However, for cleaner code, I'd strongly recommend subclassing `NSWindowController`.
- `NSWindowController` (and `NSDocument` if you decide not to subclass `NSWindowController`) can load a window from a NIB you build in Interface Builder. In fact, this is the recommended approach for creating your document windows.

Hopefully this gives you a general idea of how to approach this in Cocoa.

Comment: +1 for saying what I was trying to get across, but in a much clearer and more understandable fashion. :)

Comment: That tutorial is now 50% useless, as Apple has removed half the tech from Xcode that it relied upon. Anyone got a replacement? (Apple so far hasn't bothered - it's almost as if they've given up on Core Data themselves :( )

Comment: Apple completely supports Core Data. I don't see any signs of them abandoning it. All of the tools are still present in Xcode 4, but the UI has definitely changed. What parts of the tutorial are useless?

Answer (score 1):

You would start by creating a NIB for each of your document types; and an `NSDocument` subclass for each (use an existing document-based-app-example-NIB for the setup here). You would then set theses classes to handle your various document types in the property list of the application; insofar as I remember, there are some useful tools for this hidden somewhere in XCode.

Once that is up an running, most of the details should be handled automagically; but you might still have to fudge the File-menu about a bit, and I seem to remember there being some trouble with setting the default document type and whatnot.

On the whole, tho', it's not a lot more complex than creating an app for a single kind of documents.

PS: Do take care to ensure that you really *need* different filetypes; sometimes it might be more appropriate having several different views of the same file. Just a thought. :)

Comment: So if I get you corrent, I store my data in one file format and depending on the type of document I just display it differently? That sounds easy. But how do I create the different window types? They need to have different toolbars for example.

Comment: What I wrote sounds confusing. I mean when I have only one NSDocument class how can I associate it with different window types? Or should I only have one window as well and change the toolbar, all panels, etc.?
But would this work with the standard behavior of Cocoa? Like the "Customize Toolbar" menu function?

Comment: I'm not saying that what you necessarily want to do is to have one type; I'm just throwing it out there. If you have these kinds of concerns, you probably want different types.